# Cakephp 2.0, controller doesn't see model

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-model

I'm busy upgrading a site for a client of mine. It's my first time working with CakePHP and I'm running into issues.

I created a table named `banners` inside my database, and I made the following files:

```
Model/Banner.php
Controllers/BannersController.php
View/Banners/admin_index.ctp
```

It seems like my controller can't find the model. Whenever I try to load the page `admin_index.ctp` I get the following message: `Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.`

If i replace the contents of my public `admin_index()` and make it echo text, it does work.

I also tried adding a form to my `admin_index.ctp` by doing this

```
echo $this->Form->create('Banner');
```

This gives me another `Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.`

I have set up my model, controller, view and database exactly the way the others for posts, pages, etc are set up and i just can't seem to get it to work. Does anyone have any idea on how to fix this?

Kind Regards,

Nick

```
<?php
class Banner extends AppModel {


}
?>

<?php
class BannersController extends AppController {
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

public function admin_index(){
    $banners = $this->Banner->find('all');
    $this->set('banners', $banners);
}
?>

Stack Trace:
#0 /srv/nkuchiki/www/www.kuchiki.nl/app/webroot/index.php(111): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#1 {main}
2015-04-10 17:29:43 Error: [MissingTableException] Table banners for model Banner was not found in datasource default.
Exception Attributes: array (
  'table' => 'banners',
  'class' => 'Banner',
  'ds' => 'default',
)


Request URL: /admin/banners
Stack Trace:
#0 /srv/nkuchiki/www/www.kuchiki.nl/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(3501): Model->setSource('banners')
#1 /srv/nkuchiki/www/www.kuchiki.nl/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2905): Model->getDataSource()
#2 /srv/nkuchiki/www/www.kuchiki.nl/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php(2877): Model->_readDataSource('all', Array)
#3 /srv/nkuchiki/www/www.kuchiki.nl/app/Controller/BannersController.php(7): Model->find('all')
#4 [internal function]: BannersController->admin_index()
#5 /srv/nkuchiki/www/www.kuchiki.nl/lib/Cake/Controller/Controller.php(490): ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(Object(BannersController), Array)
#6 /srv/nkuchiki/www/www.kuchiki.nl/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(191): Controller->invokeAction(Object(CakeRequest))
#7 /srv/nkuchiki/www/www.kuchiki.nl/lib/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php(165): Dispatcher->_invoke(Object(BannersController), Object(CakeRequest))
#8 /srv/nkuchiki/www/www.kuchiki.nl/app/webroot/index.php(111): Dispatcher->dispatch(Object(CakeRequest), Object(CakeResponse))
#9 {main}
```

Comment: Turn debug mode to '2' in your `Config/core.php`.  It should give you a much more helpful error message.

Comment: Do exactly what dave has said and then share error.. Only then we can help you in debugging.

Comment: Is this being loaded with your Models class? `App::uses('AppModel', 'Model')`

Comment: Thanks for the heads up so far guys. I have enabled debugging in core. I have added the error message i got from my log in my upper post.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the advice guys. Based on the extended error message i did some research on google and found some other threads on stackoverflow.

i removed the files in my tmp/cache/models, and tmp/cache/persistent and the problem was resolved :-).

It can be really difficult to find a problem when everything seems to be programmed right.

Comment: awesome! spend a day on this. Thanks for writing the answer